# shared file system with rhcs

Tags: gfs2, rhcs

We have 2 node cluster which is attached with storage to share single parition between both cluster node. So for that we configure rhcs with gfs2. We aaded resources with gfs and ip address. So when first time I ask cluster services it represent on node 1 as i selected it with high priority. And when i reboot it , it goes on node 2 with ip and mounting gfs partition, but as soon as ndoe 1 comes back, again it acquires ip address and mounting gfs partition but that time also i can see mounting on node 2 also.

Is it correct behavior? Can we use same partition to access same files from both nodes?

Thanks,
Ben

Answer (score 0):

Its normal behavior for the cluster resource to fail back, if thats what youve set it to. You should go to 'modify domain' and set it there if this isnt wanted.

The [Redhat documentation](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Cluster_Administration/s2-config-modify-failoverdm-conga-CA.html) will describe how to set it to your requirements.